# why my css button come vertically used "data-role:contend" in jqm?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQm in my demo.It look like this .with fine UI ."new , export and import buttons are horizontally".when you scroll please check.
http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/5/

Only problem is my panel break.

But when I used jqm div (data-role :header, content , fotter).my css break it "new , export and import buttons come vertically ..why ?But my panel problem solved.
http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/12/

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a" >
        <!-- panel content goes here -->
        <label class="testSuiteId">Test Suite</label>
        <div id="tree">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>


    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Stacker</h1>
        <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-right gear"></a>


    </div><!-- /header -->


    <div data-role="content" >
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="new_h"><a href="#" class="active"><i class="new"></i>New</a>
                </li>
                <li class="export_h"><a href="#"><i class="export "></i>Export</a>
                </li>
                <li class="import_h"><a href="#"><i class="import "></i>Import</a>
                </li>
                <div class="cb"></div>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <div class="cb"></div>


        <article class="testsuitbox">
            <h1>TestSuite Name</h1>
            <input name="" type="text" class="txtfield" id="testSuiteId">
        </article>

        <div class="contentbox">
            <div class="actionbar">
                <a href="#" class="home" id="home_h"></a><a href="#" class="previous" id="previous_h"><i
                    class="iconprev"></i>Previous</a><a href="#" class="next" id="next_h"><i
                    class="iconnext"></i>Next</a>
                <a style="cursor: pointer;" id="oneLevelUp" class="oneLevelUp">Up level ^</a>
                <div class="cb"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="secondPage">
            </div>
            <div id="thirdPage">
            </div>
            <div id="firstPage">
            <div class="testsuittitle" id="testSuitConfiguration">
                Test Suite Configuration
                <!--button class="parallelbtn">
                    <!--i class="circlepointer"></i-->
                <!--/button-->
                <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" class="selectSequence_h">
                    <option value="Sequential">Sequential</option>
                    <option value="Parallel">Parallel</option>
                </select>

            </div>



            <div class="contentsubbox" id="testCaseContainer">

            </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" id="firstPageFooter">

        <button class="addtestbtn" id="addTestCase" data-theme="a" style="color: #ffffff!important;">Add Test Case</button>

    </div>








</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix CSS file found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kk2kwhlagzsi9g1/default.css

Nav bar CSS is set to:

```
header nav {
```

and because you no longer have <header> you need to change your CSS. In my last example I've replaced <header> with **data-role="header"** div. Now you need to change your CSS so it can look at this new div container.

#### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/14/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Stacker</h1>
    <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-left"></a>


</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="header">


    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="new_h"><a href="#" class="active"><i class="new"></i>New</a>
            </li>
            <li class="export_h"><a href="#"><i class="export "></i>Export</a>
            </li>
            <li class="import_h"><a href="#"><i class="import "></i>Import</a>
            </li>
            <div class="cb"></div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.header{margin:0px; padding:0px;  z-index:99999;}
.header .logobar{
    background: #4fa0d5; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: #4fa0d5; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4fa0d5 0%, #1e5799 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4fa0d5), color-stop(100%,#1e5799)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4fa0d5 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4fa0d5 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4fa0d5 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4fa0d5 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4fa0d5', endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color:#fff; font-size:2.5em; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.header .logobar a{ float:left; padding:0.5% 1%; background:#062e48; width:35px; display:block; height:34px; margin-right:10px;}
.header .logobar a i.toggleicon{background:url(../images/toggle-icon.png) no-repeat left 3px; display:block; width:34px; height:26px;}
.header nav{
    background: #226088;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #226088 0%, #13374e 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#226088), color-stop(100%,#13374e));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #226088 0%,#13374e 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #226088 0%,#13374e 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #226088 0%,#13374e 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #226088 0%,#13374e 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#226088', endColorstr='#13374e',GradientType=0 );
    margin:0px; z-index:-1px; -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #012944;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #012944;
    box-shadow:        0px 0px 3px 1px #012944}
.header nav ul li a{margin:0px; padding:0.5% 0px;  display: inline-block; box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #000;
    font-size:1.5em; width:33.3%; float:left; font-weight:normal !important; display:block;text-align:center; color:#fff !important; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000 !important;}

.header nav ul li a:hover{color:#fff !important; text-decoration:none; background: #565656;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%, #262626 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(4%,#565656), color-stop(100%,#262626));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#565656', endColorstr='#262626',GradientType=0 );  }

.header nav ul li a.active{
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSI0JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzU2NTY1NiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyNjI2MjYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%, #262626 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(4%,#565656), color-stop(100%,#262626));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #565656 4%,#262626 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#565656', endColorstr='#262626',GradientType=0 ); }
.header nav ul li a i.new{background:url(../images/icon.png) no-repeat left top; width:22px; margin-top:8px; display:inline-block; height:22px; }
.header nav ul li a i.export{background:url(../images/icon.png) no-repeat left -28px; width:30px; display:inline-block; height:30px;}
.header nav ul li a i.import{background:url(../images/icon.png) no-repeat left -60px; width:30px; display:inline-block; height:33px;}
```